# Using textoverlay and timeoverlay together

Tags: gstreamer

I have a small C project which uses GStreamer. I want to load a video and display it together with a subtitle (textoverlay) and elapsed time (timeoverlay).

My idea looks like this:

```
- create a textoverlay and set a sample subtitle
- create a timeoverlay
- create a videosink
- put the three elements in a new bin and link them: 
  textoverlay -> timeoverlay -> videosink
- use playbin2 for playback and send the video from playbin2 to the new bin
```

Here is my testing standalone application:

```
// Save as "test.c". Compile with: 
// gcc -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gstreamer-0.10 gstreamer-interfaces-0.10` test.c
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Init - GTK is only used here as a GUI hook
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    gst_init(0, NULL);

    // Path to file - juts a simple demo file
    char uri[2048];
    sprintf(&uri[0], "file:///tmp/1.mpg");

    // Playbin and URI
    GstElement *playbin2 = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin2", "playbin2");
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (playbin2), "uri", &uri[0], NULL);

    // Elements - videosink, textoverlay, timeoverlay
    GstElement *videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("sdlvideosink", "videosink");
    GstElement *textoverlay = gst_element_factory_make("textoverlay", "textoverlay");
    GstElement *timeoverlay = gst_element_factory_make("timeoverlay", "timeoverlay");

    // Set sample text in textoverlay
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(textoverlay), "text", "Test Subtitle", NULL);

    // Create bin, add elements
    GstElement *mybin = gst_bin_new("mybin");
    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (mybin), videosink);
    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (mybin), textoverlay);
    gst_bin_add (GST_BIN (mybin), timeoverlay);

    // Get sink pad for textoverlay and make it a ghostpad for bin
    GstPad *pad_textoverlay_sink = gst_element_get_pad(textoverlay, "video_sink");
    gst_element_add_pad(mybin, gst_ghost_pad_new("sink", pad_textoverlay_sink));

    // Link elements: textoverlay -> timeoverlay -> videosink
    gst_element_link_pads(textoverlay, "src", timeoverlay, "sink");
    gst_element_link_pads(timeoverlay, "src", videosink, "sink");

    // Conect the bin to the playbin
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (playbin2), "video-sink", mybin, NULL);

    // Play video
    gst_element_set_state (playbin2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // GTK Main loop
    gtk_main ();
}
```

If I link the src pad of textoverlay to the sink pad of the videosink (thus skipping timeoverlay), I get a video and a subtitle - just as expected.

If I change the code and make the sink pad of timeoverlay a ghostpad for mybin, then link the src pad of timeoverlay to videosink (thus skipping textoverlay) - I get a video with elapsed time, just as expected.

However, when I try to cascade textoverlay and timeoverlay, there's no video. It does not depend on videosink - same with xvimagesink and ximagesink. No error is shown. With gstreamer-launch it works fine, so obviously I'm doing something wrong in C - I just can't figure out what.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solves the problem is using a pipeline instead of bin.

```
GstElement *mybin = gst_pipeline_new ("my-pipeline");
```

Why it does, however, is still unclear to me. GStreamer docs say that pipeline is just a top-level bin; I found no restriction in the docs on how many elements can reside in a bin or on what can they do. On the other hand, playbin2 is internally a pipeline, therefore mybin can be a regular bin (and it works fine as a regular bin as long as only textoverlay or timeoverlay is used).

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution is to use **gst_element_link_many**:

```
gst_element_link_many(textoverlay, timeoverlay, videosink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Textoverlay expects a stream of text on the sink as well. Better run your app with GST_DEBUG="*:2" then you will see the warning about that.

And btw.
- char uri[2048];
- sprintf(&uri[0], "file:///tmp/1.mpg");
+ gchar *uri = "file:///tmp/1.mpg";
:)

Comment: More precisely, textoverlay has a text sink, but sendingtext to it is not mandatory. For my needs (a subtitling application) setting the 'text' property works fine. The second suggestion is also fine, but will not solve the problem.